# htaccess shortening url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i would like to shorten

> www.site.com/product/info/laptop to www.site.com/laptop

I used

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /product/info/$1
```

but i get 500 Internal Server Error

when i try,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s\'~%,:!?()_=&-]+)$ /product/info/$1
```

it works but i want to support the period as well, so when I include .

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s\'~%,:!?()\._=&-]+)$ /product/info/$1
```

It gives me 500 Internal Server Error

Could you explain what is going on?

Thank you

Comment: Why the double quotes? the expression should be [a-zA-Z0-9_\s\'~%,:!?()\._=&-]+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/info/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$        /%2                  [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect the browser from www.example.com/product/info/laptop to www.example.com/laptop with a "Moved Permanently" header.

If you mean you wish the shorter URL to point to the longer URL internally, then you must avoid circular redirections:

```
RewriteRule ^product/info/.*$ -                [L] # don't redirect again
RewriteRule ^(.*)$            /product/info/$1 [L] # redirect everything else
```

The first line will stop trying to redirect www.example.com/product/info/laptop to www.example.com/product/info/product/info/laptop, and so-on.

**Edit**

Based on your comment, it looks like you're also trying to redirect everything except img, phpmyadmin, etc, to index?whatever - You have to rearrange it all a bit now, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php|img|phpmyadmin|images|user|wmd|FCKeditor|map|jscalendar|aurigma|xajax_js|css|js|include|floatbox|helper|styles|ajax|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|product/info/(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L] # don't redirect these

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product/info/$1 # redirect everything else
```

I'm not 100% on the "product/info/(.*)" part of the first rewrite. If that doesn't work, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php|img|phpmyadmin|images|user|wmd|FCKeditor|map|jscalendar|aurigma|xajax_js|css|js|include|floatbox|helper|styles|ajax|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L] # don't redirect these

RewriteRule ^product/info/.*$ -                [L] # don't redirect again

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product/info/$1 [L] # redirect everything else
```

**Edit 2**

Final answer based on your comment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php|img|phpmyadmin|images|user|wmd|FCKeditor|map|jscalendar|aurigma|xajax_js|css|js|include|floatbox|helper|styles|ajax|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L] # don't redirect these

# pass controllers to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(home|browse|calendar|star|member|enter|product)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

# pass other things than controllers to /index.php?/product/info/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/product/info/$1 [L] # redirect everything else
```

Comment: Thank you so much your help. I wish the shorter URL to point to the longer URL internally, so my htaccess now looks like

Comment: RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/info/(.*)$

RewriteRule ^product/info/.*$ -                # don't redirect again

RewriteRule ^(.*)$            /product/info/$1 # redirect everything else


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|phpmyadmin|images|user|wmd|FCKeditor|map|jscalendar|aurigma|xajax_js|css|js|include|floatbox|helper|styles|ajax|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

but now this gives me

Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error..

Comment: I've updated the answer above - you need to keep those [L]'s in place, otherwise it will keep processing further rules.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
I have given up on this a few times in the past few months, and now your answers really guided me to the right direction.
I slightly modified your code and finally arrived at this

Comment: RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php|img|phpmyadmin|images|user|wmd|FCKeditor|map|jscalendar|aurigma|xajax_js|css|js|include|floatbox|helper|styles|ajax|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L] # don't redirect these



# pass controllers to index.php



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
 ^/(home|browse|calendar|star|member|enter|product)



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]



# pass other things than controllers to /index.php?/product/info/$1



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/product/info/$1 [L] # redirect everything else

Comment: Glad to help :) it can be confusing at times!
I've updated my answer with your final solution.